# Trying to understand a closure function

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I made a closure function with the help of google. The function works as it should. However, I'm not sure to know how it works.

```
function ShowQuestion(i) {
  console.log(i); // here 1 to 10 are logged immediately.
  return function() {
    console.log(i); // here the number are only logged when I mouse over on any li.
  }
}

setTimeout(function() {    
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('Previousli').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('Previousli').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children[i].onmouseover = ShowQuestion(i);
  }    
}, 10000);
```

First of all, I'm wondering why the first console.log(i) log 1 to 10 immediately after the 10 seconds time out, but the second console.log(i) log the "index" only when I mouse over a li?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm wondering why the first console.log(i) log 1 to 10 immediately after the 10 seconds time out

Because the timeout callback has a loop and calls `ShowQuestion` in a loop. The first statement of `ShowQuestion` is the `console.log`, so you see all of those, one right after another, as that loop runs.

> but the second console.log(i) log the "index" only when I mouse over a li?

Because `ShowQuestion` returns a function; the loop code assigns that function to the `onmouseover` property of the element, making it an old-fashioned event handler for the `mouseover` event. The function created by `ShowQuestion` isn't run until/unless that event occurs, and is re-run whenever that event occurs.

You may be wondering why/how that event handler can show `i` when `i` is an argument provided to `ShowQuestion` and by the time the handler is run by the `mouseover` event, `ShowQuestion` has already returned. The answer is that the function `ShowQuestion` creates is a *closure* over the context of that specific call to `ShowQuestion`, including the in-scope parameters and variables. So each of the copies of `i` from each of the calls to `ShowQuestion` survives, even though the call to `ShowQuestion` it relates to has completed.

More:

- Here on SO: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)
- On my anemic little blog: [Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Ah my eyes are open now.

Thank you sir!

Basically, ShowQuestion function run 10 times right after the timeout then never again?

Is the loop create 10 differents mouse over event, one for every li element?

Comment: @IssacNolan: That's it exactly. :-)